# How to export sklearn RandomForestClassifier python code to C code with sklearn_porter?

Tags: python, c, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use `sklearn_porter` to train a Random Forest Modell in python which then should be exported to C code.

This is my code:

```
from sklearn_porter import Porter
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import sys
sys.path.append('../../../../..')
iris_data = load_iris()

X = iris_data.data
y = iris_data.target

print(X.shape, y.shape)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=15, max_depth=None,
                             min_samples_split=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)
porter = Porter(clf, language='c')
output = porter.export(embed_data=True)

print(output)
```

but get the following error:

```
...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn_porter\Porter.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sklearn.tree.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.tree.tree
```

So I checked Porter.py and saw that the import is not done right (?) because the from statement has mistakes in it like `sklearn.tree.tree`one `.tree` is enough

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.tree.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble.weight_boosting import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble.forest import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble.forest import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.svm.classes import LinearSVC
from sklearn.svm.classes import SVC
from sklearn.svm.classes import NuSVC
from sklearn.neighbors.classification import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
```

So I corrected that but another error occured

```
...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn_porter\Porter.py", line 117, in __init__
    error = "Currently the given model '{algorithm_name}' " \
KeyError: 'algorithm_name'
```

but I couldn't correct this error...

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using python 3.8.8 and scikit-learn 0.24.1

Edit: tried it also with python 3.7.10 because on [Git](https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter) states that it is just available for python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7. On 3.7 the same error occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the problem is that `sklearn-porter` is not compatible with recent version of scikit-learn indeed for example see [this](https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter/issues/82). You may want to ask them whether they plan to support recent scikit-learn versions.

As an alternative, you may want to look at [sklearn-onxx](https://github.com/onnx/sklearn-onnx).

Answer (score 2):

The code works Using scikit-learn version 0.22.2. and Python 3.7.9!